# keras tuner `hp` variable

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to get to grips with Keras Tuner, but I am struggling to work out where the `hp` comes from.

I have a bit of inherited keras code with simple dense layers I would like to work with, which looks like so:

```
 def get_model0(hp, param0: int, param1: dict):
     start0 = tf.keras.layers.Input((param0,))
     x = start0
     for units_item in param1:
        x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(activation="relu", units=hp.Int('hidden_size', units_item/4, units_item, step=16, default=units_item) )(x)

    <<some_more_code>

    model0 = tf.keras.models.Model(inp, x, name="model0")
    return model0
```

But, this always seems to throw me a nameError on `hp`. Do I need to import anything for this to work? The examples on keras-tuner pages do not seem to suggest anything...

I am totally unsure why this is (I am a pytorch user) - any help or pointers would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I had to do:

```
hp = kt.HyperParameters()
```

before passing to the build_model.